# Custom Wordpress Excerpt not adding <p> tags

Tags: php, wordpress, function, blogs

I'm in a bit of a sticky situation with a custom excerpt function I'm using.

**Here's a link to the Pastebin with the Custom Excerpt Function:** http://pastebin.com/gK0AWQbt

**This is the blog index using the function:** http://club16.abcguide.com/blog/

Also, the code I'm using here is: `<?php echo excerpt(300); ?>`

And here's the post on the single page, with proper formatting: http://club16.abcguide.com/newsletters/jan-2012/

**Essentially the excerpt function I'm using isn't generating my `<p>` tags around elements, I'm not sure how I can modify the function to have it do this efficiently.**

Also, if I can have more control of when the excerpt ends (maybe even per post? If I could make it identify a specific class and cut there..) that would be amazing.

But focusing on the task at hand, I'm in dire need of a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default excerpt shows first 55 characters and it strips out  all html tags. If you want to increase the length of the excerpt function then you can us a filter like one given bellow, just add this code snippet in your functions.php file of your theme and wrap the function call inside a p tag in the index.php file.

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) 
{
    return 300;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

Use the_excerpt() instead of the_excerpt(300) in your index.php file inside the p tag.

```
<p class="someclass"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>
```

Comment: If you look at the blog index and single post page, I've got a bunch of '<p>' elements that I need to display, and not just the entire excerpt inside of a tag. I'm also displaying images. I need the paragraphs to stay in place so that the images stay properly positioned.

Comment: If you want to completely hack the excerpt function then take a look at this, hope it will help you more. 
http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/how-to-preserve-html-tags-in-wordpress-excerpt-without-a-plugin/

Comment: Awesome, that guide led me to a manual which gave me a perfect solution for the formatting and having control over how much is displayed. Thank you VERY much!!! :)